# How to address Geodatabase must be enabled as geodatabase admin user error?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, postgresql, esri-geodatabase

I am trying to use "enable Enterprise Geodatabase" but I am getting the following error:

```
"Geodatabase must be enabled as geodatabase admin user.Failed to execute "
```

I am using postgresql 9.1.3 database.

I have created the database named geo using this command: `createdb geo` and sed user using: `CREATE USER sde WITH SUPERUSER LOGIN PASSWORD 'sdepassword';`  and then I connected to database as sde user.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is this a answer or a question?

Comment: just edited the question

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: postgresql 9.1.3

Comment: Are you connecting to the database as the sde user?

Comment: I have created a database and sde user in postgresql using these commands : "creatdb geo" and "CREATE USER sde WITH SUPERUSER LOGIN PASSWORD 'sdepassword';" and then connect to postgresql from arccataloge.

Comment: You could edit your answers to comments into your Question to improve it for the next reader who may be a potential answerer.

Answer (score 4):

It's confusing, but databases make a distinction between users, roles, schemas, and logins.  If you failed to create an SDE login, then you would likely get this error.  Logins are a property of the master database:

```
CREATE ROLE sde LOGIN
    PASSWORD securepassword
    SUPERUSER NOINHERIT CREATEDB CREATEROLE;
```

You also need an "sde" schema in the working database

```
CREATE SCHEMA sde
    AUTHORIZATION sde;
```

A number of GRANTs are also necessary:

```
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA sde TO sde;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA sde TO public;
```

And the search path must be correct:

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname SET search_path="$user", public, sde;
```

The geodatabase tool (both UI and Python) will issue all the necessary commands if you give it leave to do so.  It's usually wise to let it do so the first couple of times, then you can review what was done and see what is necessary for custom install.  By the time you've enabled a dozen databases, you'll have written a helper script in your preferred configuration style.

Comment: now after enabling geodatbase I am getting this message: User does not have required privileges for geodatabase setup